# minitest and Rspec on same project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, minitest

I'm working on a project that uses rails default test framework and we decided to change for Rspec.
For the moment I would like to keep the old tests but with Rspec installed it seems to break the `rails test`command. It works if I remove the rspec-rails gem. Is there a way to use `rails test` with minitest without removing rspec ?

The logs :

```
rake aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `have_many' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::Benefit:Class
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:738:in `method_missing'
/home/circleci/repo/test/models/benefit_test.rb:36:in `block in <class:BenefitTest>'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:387:in `module_exec'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:387:in `subclass'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:260:in `block in define_example_group_method'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:43:in `block in expose_example_group_alias'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rspec-core-3.8.2/lib/rspec/core/dsl.rb:84:in `block (2 levels) in expose_example_group_alias_globally'
/home/circleci/repo/test/models/benefit_test.rb:4:in `<class:BenefitTest>'
/home/circleci/repo/test/models/benefit_test.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.4/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `block in require'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:257:in `load_dependency'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `require'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:50:in `block in load_tests'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:50:in `each'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:50:in `load_tests'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:39:in `run'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb:35:in `rake_run'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.3/lib/rails/test_unit/testing.rake:16:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/circleci/repo/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-12.3.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => test
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
Coverage report generated for RSpec to /home/circleci/repo/coverage. 1644 / 3636 LOC (45.21%) covered.
Exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 1):

In theory rspec could work alongside minitest, `have_many` looks like a shoulda matcher, perhaps from something like

```
describe "Thing" do
  it { should have_many :sub_things }
end
```

Do you have the shoulda-matchers gem in your Gemfile (under :test group) and Shoulda::Matchers configured in your spec or rails helper?

```
Shoulda::Matchers.configure do |config|
  config.integrate do |with|
    with.test_framework :rspec
    with.library :rails
  end
end
```

https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers to learn you more about setting it up. I'm not exactly sure but I'd guess some sort of configuration is required for it to work with minitest as well.

Comment: Indeed it seems to come from the shoulda-matchers gem. this is my gem file :
```
group :test do
  gem 'shoulda', '~> 3.5'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails'', '~> 3.8'
end
```
Unforunatly I get :
``` undefined method configure for Shoulda::Matchers:Module ``` 

probably because of the version of my shoulda matchers gem. Their documentation indicates to use this specific version in minitest ;(

Comment: That’s a bummer...guess it’s all a matter of deciding whether it’s more feasible to rewrite the specs (whick could be as easy as copy-pasting the shoulda-based examples) and ditching minitest entirely, or investing more time into trying to figure out a way to have them play nice which could work too I guess. Plissken would probably just ditch minitest and carry on with rspec but maybe you’re more conservative